# How to load a spring context from external library's spring files

Tags: java, xml, spring, eclipse, maven

I have 2 servers in my workspace which has a common code. - I'll refer them as `ServerA`and `ServerB` to make it simpler. Both servers are using Spring and Maven. 
Due to the common code, I have decided to make a library called `ServerLib` to store the common code. 
So now ServerLibrary also contains the spring xml files in its `src/resources` like the other two servers.

In ServerA main method, I call

```
List<String> springContextFiles = new ArrayList<String (Arrays.asList("spring/common.xml", "spring/serverAOnly.xml"));
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springContextFiles.toArray(new String[springContextFiles.size()]));
```

This used to work without any problem when the common code and spring xml files were in ServerA project. Now that I put them in the `ServerLib`, it no longer works and throw an error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.support.ResourceEditorRegistrar.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;)V`

[image: Error Log]

Both ServerA and ServerLib have spring version 4.1.6.RELEASE. Also, I have tried putting the spring files back to ServerA, but leaving the common java files in ServerLib. It still throws the same error.

I'm using maven to inject dependencies but in this case, ServerLib is just added in java build path as a required project to build path. It is referenced correctly as I can see the local project in Maven Dependencies list in eclipse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance.

Note:
Spring version in ServerA project are as following. Maven Dependency Tree only shows spring in 4.1.6.RELASE version
[image]

Comment: The error indicates you ae mixing jars of different versions of Spring, don't do that.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not using different versions of Spring though. They are all version 4.1.6.RELEASE.

Comment: I highly doubt that... It is either different versions of versions in different class loaders. The fact that you defined that version in maven might not lead to you actually using that version. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to check the actual versions used.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have just checked the maven dependency tree on eclipse and excluded all the spring versions which are not 4.1.6.RELEASE. However, I'm still having the same issue. I have attached the screenshot of maven dependency tree.

Comment: That isn't the output of `mvn dependency:tree` but the eclipse interpretation of the output. Just run in on the command line.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have done it also on the command line but all the spring framework dependency has a version 4.1.6.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I excluded the spring dependencies from libraries in maven – which is why my dependency tree is clean, it was bringing in old versions of spring from my local libraries which were opened in my workspace. Closing those projects got rid of the ERROR.